# Map primary colour with multiple supplier colours

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, simple-product

I am currently working for large retailer's Magento project. Retailer has two colour attributes. One is for primary colour and second one is for supplier colour which is actually acts as separate sku (simple) on configurable product view page.

We have created two attributes. primary_colour which is filterable, and supplier_colour which is configurable.

It is hard for client to manage huge number of supplier colours. So they want to map their primary colour attributes with supplier colour attributes. E.g. blue maps to Navy Blue and Sky Blue

Challenge 1:
Now client want to show colour swatches for both attributes however want to show same swatch for supplier_colour as primary colour one. As they dont want to create hundreds of swatches for different supplier colours which are same but named differently by different suppliers

Challenge 2:
When customer choose pimary colour from LHS layered navigation, then configurable product change its image to corresponding mapped supplier colour (It is quite easy if we use same configurable attribute (supplier colour) in layered navigation. However we have two separate attributes)

I am wondering if someone shed some light on this particular scenario. What is the best approach to achieve it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a map table, where you set the supplier color for main color relation manually one time?

Comment: @Amasty Yes we have got this relation from the retailer and are planning to create a map table in the magento

Answer (score 1):

When this is a big vendor, you have an ERP or something behind, so I think it is best to implement all the stuff into the import and export layer.

Then your magento is untouched and you get an order, you check what the real color name for the product is and export it correctly.

Comment: can you elaborate what are you trying to say.

Comment: Where do your products come from and where do the orders go? Do you have a third party system, like an SAP, MS Navision, Salesforce or something like this? Wherever you import your data from should do the mapping, so you only have the mapped and merged attributes in magento and when you export the orders to your system for order processing, you again map everything back.

Comment: Still not getting what are u trying to say.  we are getting Cataglogue CSV every 12 hours which have all the mapped attributes. We have already created mapping between their catalogue and Magento product types and attributes. But it does not resolve the challenges which I have stipulated earlier